# Как правильно вернуть выборку Mysql из функции C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Не могу понять как вернуть массив с выборкой из Mysql. Направьте на путь истинный, пожалуйста.

Ситуация следующая есть функция которая делает выборку из Mysql

```
    Public static ??ТипВозр.Значения?? mysql(){
    // Инициализация и подключение
          MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id,name FROM table", link);
          MySqlDataReader data;

          try
          {
              data = cmd.ExecuteReader();              
              return data;
          }
   }
```

Вопрос: как вернуть массив с данными из Mysql и потом разобрать его вне этой функции. Например, я вызываю её так

```
static void my(){
    ??? arr{};
    arr = mysql();
    while(arr in r){
       //??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
public List<User> Get(int userID)
{
    var list = new List<User>();

    using(var connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******;"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from users", connection))
        {
            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var user = new User();
                user.EmailAddress = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("email"));
                user.Password = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("passcode"));
                list.Add(user);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public class User 
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Есть и другие способы упрощающие работу с базой. Могу порекомендовать:

- [Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/739164/Entity-Framework-Tutorial-for-Beginners)
- [BLToolkit](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit)
- [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)
- [NHibernate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/)
- [llblgen](https://www.llblgen.com/Pages/Lite.aspx)